# v4l2 documentation's sample code as is (with open as 'rw')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, v4l2

I've just started using `v4l2` (for `Python 3`) on `Ubuntu 16.04.`

I'm trying to run the sample from the v4l2 Python documentation, namely:

```
$ cat demo4SO.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import v4l2
import fcntl

vd = open('/dev/video0', 'rw')
#vd = open('/dev/video0', 'r')
cp = v4l2.v4l2_capability()
fcntl.ioctl(vd, v4l2.VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, cp)

print("driver:",cp.driver)
print("card:",cp.card)
```

But am getting:

```
$ python3 demo4SO.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo4SO.py", line 6, in <module>
    vd = open('/dev/video0', 'rw')
ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode
```

I get the same error even when running with `sudo.`

Trying to open with 'w+' (or 'r+'), I get:

```
$ python3 demo4SO.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo4SO.py", line 8, in <module>
    vd = open('/dev/video0', "w+")
io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.
```

If I change 'rw' (or 'w+' or 'r+') to 'r', the code works as expected.

```
$ cat demo4SO.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import v4l2
import fcntl

#vd = open('/dev/video0', 'rw')
vd = open('/dev/video0', 'r')
cp = v4l2.v4l2_capability()
fcntl.ioctl(vd, v4l2.VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, cp)

print("driver:",cp.driver)
print("card:",cp.card)


$ python3 demo4SO.py
driver: b'uvcvideo'
card: b'Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410'
```

My username belongs to the group of the video device, so the problem does not seem to be related to permissions:

```
$ groups
openstack root sudo video staff
$ ls -ls /dev/video0
0 crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 פבר 14 11:31 /dev/video0
```

**Any idea why I cannot run the documentation's sample code as is (with 'rw')?**

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
vd = open('/dev/video0', 'rw')
```

to

```
vd = open('/dev/video0', 'rb+', buffering=0)
```

enables opening the file with O_RDWR permissions.